# Cannot connect to VM from Mac using FileZilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

In my Mac, I create a VM(CentOS) via VMware Fusion.I want to use FileZilla to load data from Mac to the VM like WinSCP.

I use the `ifconfig` get the VM's ip:`192.168.220.128`

I ping the ip in my Mac Terminal, it is ok:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:etc ldl$ ping 192.168.220.128 
PING 192.168.220.128 (192.168.220.128): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.220.128: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.286 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.220.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.198 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.220.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.377 ms
```

But I cannot connect to the VM using FileZilla from my Mac. I tested the `20`, `21`, `14147` port.

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

In my VM, I use telnet to test the `21` port.
I can connect to the ip.

```
[root@localhost src]# telnet 192.168.220.128 21
Trying 192.168.220.128...
Connected to 192.168.220.128.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
^Z^C^C^Z^Csa


quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

**Edit -2**

And I use the `ps aux` to query the vsftpd if is running, it shows running status:

```
[root@localhost src]# ps aux | grep vsftpd 
root      24464  0.0  0.0  52796   564 ?        Ss   10:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
root      26103  0.0  0.0 112644   952 pts/0    S+   11:40   0:00 grep --color=auto vsftpd
```

---

**EDIT -3**

I use the `netstat` check the `21` port, it is `vsftpd` listen.

```
[root@localhost src]# netstat -plnt 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2092/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1537/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1540/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      24464/vsftpd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1537/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1540/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1969/master
```

Comment: Did you install ftp (vsftpd or similar) on the CentOS? Is said service running? Did you open the firewall ports?

Comment: @KevinO I installed the `vsftpd` now in the VM, but can not connect yet. should I start something?

Comment: I'm not at a CentOS machine to verify all the steps, but you will need to modify the iptables to allow connectivity. There is a GUI approach for it, or edit the file directly and restart iptables. Then start the vsftp (probably via `systemctl start vsftpd`). Check `netstat -plnt` to ensure there is something listening on :21. That should allow the connection.

Comment: Can you telnet to your VM on port 21?

Comment: @ryekayo  See my EDIT-1.

Comment: @three-block looks like vsftpd is configured for ipv6. Is that what your looking to do?

Comment: @ryekayo I want to use the FileZilla upload the file from my Mac to the Virtual Machine.

Comment: @ryekayo If is because of the `vsftpd` listening the IPv6 address so I can not use the FileZilla to connect it?

Comment: If your PC is not configured for ipv6 then probably not. You should go back to your configuration and reconfigure for ipv4. Then test your connection. And another thing, logs are your friend. You should be checking the log files and posting them to your question.